# Add a variable to a list tile flutter

Tags: listview, variables, flutter

I currently have a percentage counter in a list view

Im trying to use a variable to have the text in the middle change almost in parallel with the actual bar because i am planning to have information come in from python and python is good with numbers so what can i do to get the text in the middle of the circle to be the actual var number

```
  var number = 0.7;

   class percent extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("Circular Percent Indicators"),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[


                    **new CircularPercentIndicator(
                      radius: 140.0,
                      lineWidth: 13.0,
                      animation: true,
                      percent: number,
                      **center: new Text(
                        (number),**
                        style:
                        new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),

                      circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                      progressColor: Colors.purple,
                    ),**

                  ]),
```

Here is all my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rave/flutter_rave.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
var number = 0.7;


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'assets/logo.png';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/ccs.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              height: 32,
            ),

          ],

        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[

            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://www.mobilityhouse.com/media/gene-cms/c/s/css-combo-stecker-468px.png'),
              ),
              title: Text('CCS'),
              subtitle: Text('Example: Ford Fusion, Hyundai Ioniq, Volkswagen e-golf'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/gb-t-chinese-standard-ev-charger-connector-outline-icon-electric-car-charging-plug-gb-t-china-outline-icon-124469668.jpg'),
              ),
              title: Text('GB/T'),
              subtitle: Text('Example:BYD, Chineese manufacurers'),
              onTap: () {
                return showDialog<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('GB/T'),
                      content: const Text('Sorry! We do not have any chargers with this charging port'),

                      actions: <Widget>[

                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://w1.pngwave.com/png/342/73/231/electricity-symbol-electric-vehicle-chademo-battery-charger-combined-charging-system-charging-station-bmw-i3-car-png-clip-art.png'),
              ),
              title: Text('Chademo'),
              subtitle: Text('Example: Nissan Leaf, Mitsubishi Mi-ev'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomgePage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ),

    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute {

}
class MyHomgePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomgePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Center(child: Text('Sorry! This Charging port is currently not supported')),
    );
  }
}
 class percent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Circular Percent Indicators"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[


                new CircularPercentIndicator(
                  radius: 140.0,
                  lineWidth: 13.0,
                  animation: true,
                  percent: number,
                  **center: new Text(
                    (number),**
                    style:
                    new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),

                  circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                  progressColor: Colors.purple,
                ),

              ]),
        ),
      );
    }
  }




class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),

      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[


              new CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 140.0,
                lineWidth: 13.0,
                animation: true,
                percent: number,
                **center: new Text(
                  print(number + "/150");
                  style:**
                  new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                footer: new Text(
                  "Sales this week",
                  style:
                  new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
                ),
                circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                progressColor: Colors.purple,
              ),

            ]),
      ),

      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Charging Port'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstRoute()),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => percent()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call **setState** wherever you are manipulating the number, in order to redraw the UI.

example:

```
setState(() {
  number +=1;
});
```